# angular-calendar subFn is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I having troubles using the angular 5 calendar component  https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar

The calendar renders perfectly, including events etc.
However, Using *mwlCalendarPreviousView* and *mwlCalendarNextView* directives do not work.

Clicking on then do give the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: subFn is not a function
    at CalendarPreviousViewDirective.onClick (angular-calendar.js:239)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PlanningOverview.html:58)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13581)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15090)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14677)
```

Navigating to the source of that *onClick* method shows me the following:

```
 /**
  * @hidden
  * @return {?}
  */
  CalendarNextViewDirective.prototype.onClick = function () {
        var /** @type {?} */ addFn = {
            day: addDays,
            week: addWeeks,
            month: addMonths
        }[this.view];
        this.viewDateChange.emit(addFn(this.viewDate, 1));
    };
    return CalendarNextViewDirective;
```

Which shows that *subFn* is indeed not a function.

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't find what...

(I'm using angular-calendar 0.23.2 on Angular 5.0.00)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've shown that the code has bug. You've found it and stated it. What do you want to do now?

Comment: I'm using the angular-calender library in my angular app. So am I using the directives of that library. The clicking on the directives do give an error. 
On the demo site, the directives do work.

Comment: And the library has a bug. You've found it. Without changing the library code, you cannot do anything.

Comment: The library seems to work perfectly on their demo site. That's why I think it's something on my end...

Comment: For the record,  the solution is really simple: the above code shows that `addFn` will result in a function if this.view resolves to either `'day'`, `'week'` or `'month'`. In my case, just adding this field as a string in my component, and initializing it with the value `'month'` solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue using Angular 6 and angular-calendar 0.25.2. I was setting the `[view]` attribute incorrectly. I had `[view]="month"`, but the `[view]` MUST be set to a variable in the `controller`, e.g. in the HTML: `[view]='myView'` and in the controller `myView: string = 'month'`

Answer (score 1):

**[view]="month"** change to **view="month"**

Comment: [view]="'month'" should also work, note the next single quotes to ensure its a string